# C++ Ternary operator logic

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I'm having trouble figuring out what this if statement is doing. This is not my code so I am simply trying to understand what the Ternary operator is doing.

```
    if((model[STRIDE].isLogging == true ? model[STRIDE].value           : g_uiStride)   == g_uiStride &&
       (model[NUMVERTS].isLogging == true ? model[NUMVERTS].value       : NumVertices)  == NumVertices &&
       (model[PRIMCOUNT].isLogging == true ? model[PRIMCOUNT].value     : primCount)    == primCount &&
       (model[STARTINDEX].isLogging == true ? model[STARTINDEX].value   : startIndex)   == startIndex)
    {
```

Comment: do you in general know how ternary operator works?

Comment: How much C++ do you know? Have you started with a good book?

Comment: Pfff, I'm having trouble with that formula too. The bits that look like `true ? model[STARTINDEX].value   : startIndex` for example. Doesn't that make you frown too? Sure I can figure it out, but it sure might have used some more parentheses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#1. 
if (model[STRIDE].isLogging is true then 
    RESULT1 = (model[STRIDE].value == g_uiStride) else
    RESULT1 = (g_uiStride == g_uiStride)
   )   

#2. 
if (model[NUMVERTS].isLogging is true then 
    RESULT2 = (model[NUMVERTS].value == NumVertices) else
    RESULT2 = (mVertices == NumVertices)
   )        

#3. 
if (model[PRIMCOUNT].isLogging is true then
    RESULT3 = (model[PRIMCOUNT].value == primCount) else
    RESULT3 = (primCount == primCount)
   }   

#4. 
if (model[STARTINDEX].isLogging is true then
    RESULT4 = (model[STARTINDEX].value == startIndex) else
    RESULT4 = (startIndex == startIndex)
   )   

if (RESULT1 && RESULT2 && RESULT3 && RESULT4) {
    /* yay */
} else {
    /* damn */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First,

```
(model[STRIDE].isLogging == true ? model[STRIDE].value : g_uiStride) == g_uiStride
```

could be written:

```
(model[STRIDE].isLogging ? model[STRIDE].value : g_uiStride) == g_uiStride
```

the ternary

```
model[STRIDE].isLogging ? model[STRIDE].value : g_uiStride
```

checks to see if `model[STRIDE].isLogging` is true.  If it is, it takes the value `model[STRIDE].value`. If not, it takes the value `g_uiStride`. This is then compared to `g_uiStride`.

So, if it isn't logging, then this portion is automatically true because `g_uiStride` is compared to itself.  If it is logging, it is true if `mode[STRIDE].value == g_uiStride`
and

Comment: But because model[STRIDE].value is an integer and model[STRIDE].isLogging is boolean does that mean that model[STRIDE].value is receiving either a 1 or a 0

Comment: How do you know that comparison-to-self evaluates to true? Have you ever overloaded operators or used `double`s?

Comment: user1143896: model[STRIDE].value is not assigned the result.  The result of the ternary statement replaces the entire statement.

Comment: Kerrek SB: my c++ days were a long time ago - I don't know what you mean.  Are you saying == could have been overloaded?

Answer (score 1):

In general the ternary conditional operator uses a condition to choose between two alternatives:

```
condition ? first_alternative : second_alternative
```

In this case it is *very* unnecessarily complicated by comparing to true and one object to itself

```
if((model[STRIDE].isLogging == true ? model[STRIDE].value : g_uiStride) == g_uiStride
```

This can be reduced to

```
if((model[STRIDE].isLogging ? model[STRIDE].value : g_uiStride) == g_uiStride
```

which is also equivalent to

```
if (model[STRIDE].value == g_uiStride || !model[STRIDE].isLogging
```

telling us that either `value` is equal to some global value, or we don't care because we are not logging anyway.

Comment: Does it have the same short-circuiting? Also, you may be hastily assuming that `g_uiStride == g_uiStride` is always `true`, which we don't know.

Comment: We don't know anything for sure, but assuming things like that there is no `operator[]` overload that calls `abort()` I think it is close enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is as follows:

```
(condition) ? value_for_true_condition : value_for_false_condition
```

`(model[STRIDE].isLogging == true ? model[STRIDE].value           : g_uiStride)` first checks to see if the `isLogging == true`, the (condition). If the condition is true the `model[STRIDE].value` value is used, if not true the `g_uiStride` value is used.

The statement as a whole checks the values on all those members of model, but only if the member `.isLogging == true`. Otherwise it uses the default value. Note that this statement will always be true if all members have `.isLogging` variable set to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
blah = (model[STRIDE].isLogging == true ? model[STRIDE].value           : g_uiStride)
```

is the same as

```
if  (model[STRIDE].isLogging) {
   blah =  model[STRIDE].value ;
} else {
   blah =  g_uiStride;
}
```